# regex to get all JavaScript variable names and values from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, format, newline

say I have the following string:

```
let code = `
      var x = 4;
      var y=9,
          w=8
      var z=8080
      other()
      x=12

`
```

How do I write a regex that gets all of the variable declarations? In this case, I want to return all statements, and no expressions, so exclude the `other()` and `x=12` part. So far I have

```js
let results = `
      var x = 4;
      var y=9,
          w=8
      var z=8080
      other()
      x=12
      
    `.match(/(var)(.*?)(;|,|\n)/g);
    
console.log(results);
```

But I couldn't figure out how to include the w=8 part also, since that's also a declaration statement, while excluding the expressions. I tried `.match(/(var|\n)(.*?)(;|,|\n)/g)` but that also returns x=12, which I don't want. **I need to also return all statement blocks even if there is a comma right before it (either on a previous line, or previous character, anything that would normally allow a variable declaration).**

Any idea how to do this with regex?

EDIT:

with uglifyjs I'm able to do the following (which is the result I want):

```js
let strin = `
      var x = 4;
      var y=9,
          w=8,
          kk = {
              ok:1234
          },
    p,
    a = undefined
      var z=8080
      other()
      x=12
     
    `
let results = UglifyJS.parse(strin).body.filter(x=>x.__proto__.TYPE == "Var")
.map(x=>
     x.definitions.map(y=>({
        name:y.name.name,
        value:y.value ? findInPos(y.value.start, y.value.end,strin) : undefined
     })),
    
).flat()
function findInPos(start, end,str) {
    return str.substring(
        start.pos,
        end.endpos
    );
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://yaakovyitzchak.github.io/coby/uglify.js">
</script>
```

But it seems a bit overkill just to extract the *string* value of each variable? (I don't need to evaluate it, just get the string value like so)

Comment: why you want to use regex for such usecases ? why not AST ?

Comment: @CodeManiac because I don't know what AST is. enlighten me :)

Comment: @CodeManiac I just googled it and came up with things like https://github.com/acornjs/acorn this seems a bit overkill, as I'm not trying to parse all of the javascript of an entire file, only the variable declarations, and I'm only 1 step away from doing it with built-in regex. I prefer not to use any external libraries

Comment: Here you can play around with AST https://astexplorer.net/ , it is a parser which parses grammar of language, and you can modify as per your need

Comment: Using regex is not a good practice, i can help finding solution to your current regex but that more error prone. that's the reason why i am suggesting to use `AST`

Comment: Regexen are the wrong tool, even with the enhancements of modern regex engines. The task requires a source code parse unless you can constrain the permissible code structure (most certainly it would still be a pain in the ass).

Comment: @CodeManiac OK then is there a reallylightweight AST to use? (and for the record I would still like to resolve the regex problem, just for fun)

Comment: @collapsar what do u mean by " constrain the permissible code structure "?

Comment: @bluejayke Note that matches of the patterns you use to identify `var` declarations may occur within string literals, possibly template literals. Declarations may occur at arbitrary places in the statement tree, not just at the beginning of a function. I am not sure that you are 'only 1 step away' from the solution.

Comment: @blujayke With 'constraints' I mean guarantees that your code follows certain conventions and has some predefined structure. E.g. var declarations only at the beginning of a function, 1 declaration per source line, no control structures ...

Comment: Don't use regex. You'll run into caveats inside caveats inside caveats. How would you handle ``const a = `${b(`${c}`)` ``? What about `const {a} = ...`? This problem is a tricky one but it has been solved over and over by open source, ready-to-use AST.

Comment: Wonderful intro on the subject: https://alligator.io/js/traversing-ast/

Comment: @NinoFiliu I see where the problem could lie, although I'm not trying to evaluate the value, I'm just trying to get the actual text it is set to, and the evaluation will take place another way

Comment: @CodeManiac can u still help to find the solution for this, not to evaluate the var, but simply to get the string of what it's set to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task can be nicely solved with TypeScript Compiler API, as it can parse not only TypeScript but JavaScript code too. Since TypeScript compiles into JavaScript - there should be no problem to integrate the following TS snippet into a JS project.

See [demo](https://repl.it/repls/LimitedFruitfulClient)

```
import ts from "typescript";

const code = `
    var x = 4;
    var y=9,
        w=8
    var z=8080
    other()
    x=12
`;

const sf = ts.createSourceFile(
    "test.js",
    code,
    ts.ScriptTarget.ES2017,
    true,
    ts.ScriptKind.JS,
);

sf.forEachChild((n) => {
    if (ts.isVariableStatement(n)) {
        n.declarationList.declarations.forEach((decl) => {
            const name = decl.name.getText();
            const value = decl.initializer?.getText();
            console.log(`${name} = ${value}`);
        });
    }
});
```

The code above prints the following output to console:

```
x = 4
y = 9
w = 8
z = 8080
```